# How to get specific key when i click on values of an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, foreach

I have one array (i.e. $a in below) when i click on array href value how to get that specific key of an array.

```
<?php

$a = array(
    'google' => array('fff','sss','http://www.goole.com'),
    'yahoo' => array('qqq','www','http://www.yahoo.com'),
    'gmail' => array('zzz','xxx','http://www.gmail.com')
);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($a);
    echo '</pre>';
    foreach ($a as $key=>$value) {
        echo "<strong>".$key."</strong>";
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<a href="'.$value[2].'">Click Here</a>';
    }
?>
```

In above e.g.
when i click on 'Click Here' value of an array i have three specific keys also.
onclick how to get that particular key.
when click on http://www.google.com then it return google key,
when click on http://www.yahoo.com then it return yahoo key,....etc.

Comment: Did you tried something? You should use javascript.

Comment: Google out for `array_search` function of PHP

Comment: what do mean? do you want to get additional keys for certain key? Like 'ffff', 'sss' for  http://www.google.com? In what form do you expect to get returned value?

Comment: i wan't specific key when i click on value of an array, how do this using javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// 2 is column num
$key = array_search("http://www.yahoo.com" ,  array_column($a , 2));
echo 'key is : '.$key
```

Answer (score 1):

Use on click event on href like:

```
foreach ($a as $key=>$value) {
            echo "<strong>".$key."</strong>";
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<a onClick="alert(/' <?= $key ?> /')" href="'.$value[2].'">Click Here</a>';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

php part:

```
 <?php
...
    foreach ($a as $key=>$value) {
        echo "<strong>".$key."</strong>";
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<a data-sitekey="'.$key.'"  href="'.$value[2].'">Click Here</a>';
    }
?>
```

javascript part:

```
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var sitekey = e.target.getAttribute('data-sitekey');
    if (sitekey) {
      console.log(sitekey);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo '<a href="'.$value[2].'">Click Here</a>';
```

To

```
echo "<a href='##' onClick='return alert(\"$key\")' >Click Here</a>";
```